# Method Calling from another class

Tags: android, class, methods

When I call the method SWITCHON() from another class, It doesn't function as required. SWITCHON() changes the state of a device. I think the whole class should be run for SWITCHON() method to work.

Can you please advice me on how I would make SWITCHON() run the whole class or if its called will function properly.

note: this class searches for similar devices on LAN using UDP protocol

thanks

---- I want to execute a class from another activity ----

```
/**

 * It displays the list of found WeMoDevices, which can be refreshed,
 * notify about additional and removal of a WeMoDevice
 * and provide ability to control the state of the WeMoDevices

 */
 public class WemoActivity extends Activity implements NotificationListener, 
                                                  OnClickListener, 
                                                  OnItemClickListener{
private ListView mListView;
private Button mRefreshButton;
private View mProgressBar;
public Button ONButton;
private WeMoSDKContext mWeMoSDKContext = null;
private String DeviceName= "uuid:Socket-1_0-221412K1100F3A";

public static String newState;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wemo);

    mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    mRefreshButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.refresh_button);
    mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    mRefreshButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    mWeMoSDKContext = new WeMoSDKContext(getApplicationContext());      
    mWeMoSDKContext.addNotificationListener(this);

    ONButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.ON);






ONButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

     SWITCHON();

}


});}




/**
 * Refresh the list of found devices on first launch
 * and on coming into foreground
 */
@Override
protected void onStart() {      
    refresh();
    super.onStart();
}

/**
 * Stop WeMoSDKContext on application close
 */
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    mWeMoSDKContext.stop();
    super.onDestroy();
}

/**
 * Listens the WeMoDevice events
 * Updates ListView on REFRESH_LIST event, show notification on ADD_DEVICE, REMOVE_DEVICE
 * and change state of corresponding ListItem of ListView on CHANGE_STATE event 
 * 
 *event the event
 *udn the UDN of WeMoDevice provided the event
 */
@Override
public void onNotify(final String event, final String udn) {
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            WeMoDevice wemoDevice = mWeMoSDKContext.getWeMoDeviceByUDN(udn);

            if (event.equals(WeMoSDKContext.REFRESH_LIST)) {
                ArrayList<String> udns = mWeMoSDKContext.getListOfWeMoDevicesOnLAN();
                ArrayList<WeMoDevice> wemoDevices = new ArrayList<WeMoDevice>(); 

                for (String udn : udns) {
                    WeMoDevice listDevice = mWeMoSDKContext.getWeMoDeviceByUDN(udn);
                    if (listDevice != null && listDevice.isAvailable()) {
                        wemoDevices.add(listDevice);
                    }
                }
                mListView.setAdapter(new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), 0, wemoDevices));
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);                  
                mRefreshButton.setEnabled(true);
            } else if (wemoDevice == null) {
                //do nothing because of incorrect notification
            } else if (event.equals(WeMoSDKContext.ADD_DEVICE)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                               getString(R.string.notification_add) + wemoDevice.getFriendlyName(), 
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
            } else if (event.equals(WeMoSDKContext.REMOVE_DEVICE)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                               getString(R.string.notification_remove) + wemoDevice.getFriendlyName(),
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (event.equals(WeMoSDKContext.CHANGE_STATE) || event.equals(WeMoSDKContext.SET_STATE)) {
                for(int i = 0; i <= mListView.getLastVisiblePosition() - mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); i++) {
                    ListItem listItem = (ListItem)mListView.getChildAt(i);
                    if (listItem.getDevice().getUDN().equals(udn)) {
                        listItem.setState(wemoDevice.getState().split("\\|")[0]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }               
        }
    }); 
}

/**
 * The adapter to ListView
 * 

 */
private class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<WeMoDevice> {
    private ArrayList<WeMoDevice> mDevices;

    /**
     * Constructor 
     * 
     * context application context
     * resource (not used)
     * devices the array of WeMoDevices to display
     */
    public Adapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<WeMoDevice> devices) {
        super(context, resource, devices);
        mDevices = devices;
    }

    /**
     * Creates ListItem corresponding to WeMoDevice
     *   
     *  position the position of WeMoDevice in entry array
     *  convertView the created view, corresponded to the WeMoDevice
     * @ parent (not used)
     * 
     * @return created ListItem view
     */
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = new ListItem(getApplicationContext());
        }
        ((ListItem)convertView).setDevice(mDevices.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }
}

/**
 * Handle the click on refresh button 
 * and update the device list
 */
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.refresh_button) {
        refresh();
    }       
}

/**
 * Updates the list of WeMoDevices in WeMoSDKContext
 */
private void refresh() {
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mRefreshButton.setEnabled(false);
    mWeMoSDKContext.refreshListOfWeMoDevicesOnLAN();
}

/**
 * Change the state of a WeMoDevice 
 * 
 * list ListView
 *  view ListItem
 * position the position of current ListItem in ListView
 *  id the id of the current view
 */
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View view, int position, long id) {



    WeMoDevice device = ((ListItem)view).getDevice(); 



    // change the state of switches 

    String state = device.getState().split("\\|")[0];


         newState = WeMoDevice.WEMO_DEVICE_ON;

        if (state.equals(WeMoDevice.WEMO_DEVICE_ON) || state.equals(WeMoDevice.WEMO_DEVICE_STAND_BY)) {
            newState = WeMoDevice.WEMO_DEVICE_OFF;
        }

        mWeMoSDKContext.setDeviceState(newState, device.getUDN());
        ((ListItem)view).setState(WeMoDevice.WEMO_DEVICE_UNDEFINED);
}


public void SWITCHON(){



    mWeMoSDKContext.setDeviceState(WeMoDevice.WEMO_DEVICE_ON, DeviceName);
}

public void SWITCHOFF(){


    mWeMoSDKContext.setDeviceState(WeMoDevice.WEMO_DEVICE_OFF, DeviceName);
}



}
```

Comment: the device should be found first for the method to work and change the state. how do I make the whole class work from another class

Answer (score 0):

You should put your WeMoSDKContext and switchOn() method in a separate class that you can access from any Activity (e.g. ManagerWeMo). Then, you could call ManagerWeMo.switchOn().

UPDATE:

Whatever code you need to have executed should be contained in ManagerWeMo. If there is code in your Activity that depends on the outcome of what ManagerWeMo does, then set up your Activity as listener interface, pass it to ManagerWeMo, and have ManagerWeMo report back to your Activity.

Comment: this is how I would call the method from another class I assume ? yes I did that. but i have a problem that the method needs the whole class to be executed that when it is called it would change the state. calling it from the another class without executing the whole class= not called if you understand me .

Comment: Thanks you for trying to help me! okay I think this is what I need to do and that you understand me. can you please just try to explain it a little more in code sense to me, as Im a beginner :)  and is there an easier way ?